# difference between cell and octave_map in oct file

Tags: octave

I need to return a big array of struct from inside an oct file function. Should i use Cell datatype or octave_map? From documentation I could not make out which one is more applicable.

Thanks
Shash

Comment: If you want to return a struct, use octave_scalar_map or octave_map. If you want to return a cell, use Cell. I don't understand the problem here.

Comment: somewhere in the documentation it is written that if you want to access array of struct, one needs to use octave_map. I want to return an array of struct but there are no examples as to how to create an array of struct using octave_map. Should i use Array<octave_map> or Array <octave_scalar_map> or something else?

Comment: just to add to it. I was able to create an array of Cell by a simple call Cell(n,1). But I suppose this is inefficient because I want an array of struct not cell.

Answer (score 1):

Use octave_map if you want a structure array (in constrast to octave_scalar_map). In that case "contents" returns a Cell which may have more than one element.

You should also have a look at oct-map.h and examples/code/structdemo.cc

And read the manual part https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Structures-in-Oct_002dFiles.html#Structures-in-Oct_002dFiles

Comment: I have to create an array of struct not access it. I want a simple example which allows me contruct an array of struct inside an oct-file and pass it to m code. With Cell(nrows,1) I am able to do it. But can I do the same with octave_map class and how? If there are no performance issues I am happy with what i have done.